# html Text Input blocked. Only available through right button clicking

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, input

I'm developing a test page...

http://www.voradabo.com/iMcuLast/index_clean.html

and, while checking its functionality found that the  elements are "blocked" and only accesible to users if they "right click" over them... this is a strange and unexpected side effect that I need to solve ASAP... I've remade the code a lot of times but nothing seems to work... please help, I've run out of ideas!

thanks in advance for anyone willing to help me solve this "puzzling mistery"

Comment: which elements? the page seems ok to me. did you try other browsers?

Comment: @aleksv In the mid of the page exits two input fields. If you click in -with the left mouse button- you won't get a cursor into it. You have to use the right mouse button. I tried it with FF 3.6.17, Chrome 11, IE8. With IE6 and 7 you will get a normal access to the input fields.

Comment: that is the weirdest thing ever! I don't know why the two textboxes can't be clicked on. I'm using FF4.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with line 43 in `js_dragDropCookies.js`:

```
$(".recibeDrag").disableSelection();
```

If you take that one line out, it works. However, it's understandable why you want to disable the selection, so it might be better to work around it.

Right after the above line you can bind an event yourself to the contained input elements and call `stopPropagation()` in order to prevent `disableSelection()` to capture it:

```
$(".recibeDrag input").bind("mousedown",function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: I tested the tip from Mohammed, it worked fine and used the code but now I'm going to replace it with yours because is perfect... you made it finally work!!! I was starting to think that there were no solution. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange indeed. How about adding some sort of:

```
$("#geoCultura div div input").click(function() {
  $(this).focus();
});
```

To force the I-beam to show up when it gets clicked on.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed!!! It worked perfectly... At least I can now show the prototype to the client in time.

Comment: @Juan, When people like the answer, they usually select it as the correct one and sometimes even upvote it :-) But still, this is just a hack, the real answer is to remove that disableSelection() like @DathJDG suggested in his answer.